# Age Calculator Help in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The code here doesn't work properly. when I put an age in the same year etc 15/02/2003 doesn't change the year to 17 it stays at 16 
here's the code:

```vb
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String


c = TextBox2.Text
b = TextBox1.Text
a = TextBox3.Text

Dim age As New DateTime(a, b, c)

Dim Year As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, age, Now,) - 1
Dim Month As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, age, Now) Mod 12
Dim Day As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, age, Now)
Answer.Text = Year & " Years, " & Month & " Months old"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an accurate age calculator:

```
Private Sub GetCurrentDateDifference(startDate As Date,
                                     ByRef years As Integer,
                                     ByRef months As Integer,
                                     ByRef days As Integer)
    GetDateDifference(startDate, Date.Today, years, months, days)
End Sub

Private Sub GetDateDifference(startDate As Date,
                              endDate As Date,
                              ByRef years As Integer,
                              ByRef months As Integer,
                              ByRef days As Integer)
    startDate = startDate.Date
    endDate = endDate.Date

    If startDate > endDate Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("The 'startDate' value must not be greater than the 'endDate' value.")
    End If

    years = 0
    months = 0
    days = 0

    If startDate = endDate Then
        Return
    End If

    Do
        years += 1
        startDate = startDate.AddYears(1)
    Loop While startDate < endDate

    If startDate = endDate Then
        Return
    End If

    years -= 1
    startDate = startDate.AddYears(-1)

    Do
        months += 1
        startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1)
    Loop While startDate < endDate

    If startDate = endDate Then
        Return
    End If

    months -= 1
    startDate = startDate.AddMonths(-1)

    days = (endDate - startDate).Days
End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim years As Integer
    Dim months As Integer
    Dim days As Integer

    Console.Write("Please enter your date of birth (M/dd/yyyy): ")

    Dim dob = Date.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "M/dd/yyyy", Nothing)

    GetCurrentDateDifference(dob, years, months, days)

    Console.WriteLine($"You are {years} years, {months} months and {days} days old")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: How about a Try...Catch in Sub Main to catch the error you throw?

Comment: @Mary, in Production code, possibly so. That said, in Production code, I'd probably be validating the input and reprompting the user, negating the need for exception handling. That part is really beyond the scope of the question.